# IE8 asking for credentials when opening xls files office 2007

Tags: excel, internet-explorer-8

I'm using a 3rd party software which stores office documents and the front-end is a web-client.

Didn't have this issue when used with Office 2003.

With office 2007 when I try to open the document from IE it asks for Windows credentials, I can then cancel that and it would still open the document.

However if I click on 'Save' rather than 'Open' it saves the document without asking for any credentials.

I have applied the following Microsoft KB, but no result:
http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?id=943280

Does IE behave different when you click on 'Open' or 'Save' other than one you choose the location and the other stores it in a temp (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files)

Also tested on other browsers, Chrome and Firefox and it works fine, but the 3rd party software only supports IE.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the file is "unblocked" AND if that fails, try and set the location you are opening it from to trusted (in IE - Trusted Sites).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that, yes I have added it to Trusted Sites, not sure what you mean by making sure the file is "unblocked"

Comment: If the document is perceived to have come from an untrustworthy source, Windows will mark it as blocked.  If you look on the properties for the file, there is an additional "tick" under size, date, etc.

Comment: Just checked, it's not blocked either

Comment: Anyone else any ideas?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, did you already solve this?